# Chrome App Prevent JS from loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm attempting to create a Chrome App in which I have two HTML pages.  `index.html` and `settings.html`

I've created three javascript files:

- main.js
- settings.js
- utils.js.

  `utils.js` is a set of methods to register events and other helper type activities.

  When I execute my application `settings.js` appears to be executing even though that html page hasn't opened.

  The intended functionality is that settings.html calls `settings.js` in the head.  Inside of `$(document).ready()` I register two event listeners.  What is happening is that when the entire application opens, `settings.js` is executed and because of this it's registering an event listener to a dom element that doesn't exist yet.

  How do I prevent settings.js from executing on entry of the entire application?

Full code less the html bits below

utils.js:

```
var eventTypes = {
  'click': 0,
  'on': 1
};

var save = function(key, value) {
    chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}, function() {
    // Notify that we saved.
    console.log('Settings saved');
  });
};

var load = function(key) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(key, function(myobject) {
    console.log(myobject);

    settings.key = myobject;
  });
};

var registerEventListener = function(event, className, callback) {
  switch(event) {
    case eventTypes.click:
      registerOnClick(className, callback);
    break;
    case eventTypes.on:
      registerOn(className, callback);
    break;
  }
};

var registerOnClick = function(className, callback) {
  $(className).click(function() {
    callback();
  });
  console.log(className + ' registered!');
};

var registerOn = function(className, callback) {
  $(className).on('click', function() {
    callback();
  });
};

var openSettings = function() {
  console.log('Opening settings!');

  chrome.app.window.create(
    'settings.html',
    {
      id: 'settingsWindow',
      bounds: {width: 800, height: 600}
    }
  );

  console.log('Done opening settings');
};

var saveSettings = function() {
  console.log('Saving settings!');
};

var cancelSettings = function() {
  console.log('Canceling settings!');
};

// Smooth scrolling
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Register event listeners
  registerEventListener(eventTypes.click, '.settingsIcon', openSettings);
  console.log(settings);
});
```

settings.js:

```
var cancelSettings = function() {
  console.log('Cancel settings!');
};

var saveSettings   = function() {
  console.log('Save settings!');
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  registerEventListener(eventTypes.on, '.cancelSettings', cancelSettings);
  registerEventListener(eventTypes.on, '.saveSettings',   saveSettings);
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "HelloWorld",
  "short_name": "HelloWorld",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",

  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/img/icons/16/icon_16.png",
    "128": "assets/img/icons/128/icon_128.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "webview",
    "storage"
  ],

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["assets/js/jquery/jquery.min.js",
                  "assets/js/bootstrap.js",
                  "assets/js/background.js",
                  "assets/js/utils/utils.js",
                  "assets/js/settings.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/utils/utils.js"></script>

  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

settings.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/utils/utils.js"></script>

  <script src="assets/js/settings.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function $(document).ready() it is executed when the DOM is ready, according to the jquery documentation.

What you can to try is move the script tag with settings.js at the end of your body.

So your file will be executed when the document is ready.

Just a test to check if the problem is the DOM not ready.

Comment: I'll try but considering the console.log is executed when index.html is entered where I have no reference I'd guess this will not work either

Comment: Are the tags you referenced create dynamically from another piece of Javascript?